# Inputting Japanese characters?

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I am not a Japanese speaker, but I know a few words, mostly Pokémon names... In fact, in many cases the Japanese name will pop up in my head before the English one.

But I want to be able to type アブソル instead of "Abusoru" because the Romaji makes it look silly.

However at present the only way I can do this on my phone is to find an online converter and copy the result from there. Hardly ideal. But I can't find Japanese input methods anywhere in the keyboard settings. Plenty of other writing systems like Greek, Arabic, and I think Chinese, but no Japanese. Am I simply overlooking an option, or is there something I need to do to get such support on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Google Japanese Input: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese

Swype keyboard has Japanese language built in as well: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.dtc

Answer (score 1):

I will show you the way/tip (steps by steps) how to config the keyboard for any language on Android OS phone (I'm using Android 9)

1. Open any text editor app or web-browser which you can call the keyboard. In my phone, I'm opening Chrome

[image]

2. Press and hold on Space-bar key to call Change Keyboard screen

[image]

3. If there's not the support keyboard for the language that you want, select option LANGUAGE SETTINGS to go to the screen with the list of keyboards are added

[image]

4. If you want to add more keyboard, select button ADD KEYBOARD  to go to the screen that allow you select more keyboard --> find out your desired language and proceed to adding

[image]

5. Open any text editor again, then Press and hold on Space-bar key to call Change Keyboard screen --> select your desired language, in my case I selected Japanese (if I typed "ka" it will displayed by "か")

[image]